Installing Lubuntu on Trekstor Surftab twin 11.6
I have a problem with installing Lubuntu on my Trekstor Surftab twin 11.6, the problem is that the BIOS won't boot from the USB (I used Rufus). I even tried to disable safe boot and changing the boot order.
Someone can help?
Thanks :)

Does this answer your question? Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot

You've provided few specifics....  I don't know what release you're asking about, nor what version.. for example a problem existed with the original 22.04 version of calamares that had issues, but it was fixed in later ISOs.. but you gave no specifics. Your details (I don't know your hardware thus am ignoring that detail) imply a user procedural error as you've not ruled any of those out. eg. did you verify your ISO, you mention RUFUS where version of rufus matters for some releases (you gave no specifics) unless CLONE is used (you didn't say how written). Did you verify ISO write? etc

Sounds like the problem I had with my Microsoft Surface Go. Have you tried using Ventoy? It's software you can put on a USB drive which allows multiple ISOs on the same drive.
Additionally, if you have already got Linux on it you might be able to set the boot order from the command prompt by using the efibootmgr command. This also worked on the Surface Go. Come back to me if I can help any further.
